# What is the purpose of the 127.0.1.1 entry in /etc/hosts?

Tags: debian, hosts

Been googling this but found very ambiguous answers and I'm curious if I should modify these values, my VPS hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   debian
144.17.4.xx porter.info     porter
...
```

Everything works fine but I'm curious about the "127.0.1.1 debian" part, should I keep it or rename it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debian Installer creates this entry for a system **without a permanent IP address** as a workaround for some software (e.g., GNOME)

For a system with a permanent IP address, that permanent IP address should be used here instead of 127.0.1.1

here is the complete [document](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution)

Comment: Having the 127.0.1.1 line in place should not be harmful even if the system has a permanent IP address. However, the name `debian` should probably be replaced by the actual hostname of the system. The benefit of having the line in place (with the correct hostname) is to ensure the system can resolve its own hostname to a working IP address even if it has networking issues.

Comment: yes that's true. normally i just delete this line ;) i prefer using ip addresses or custom hostnames like node-1,node-2,etc

Comment: Thank you guys! Much clearer now!

Comment: What I do not understand about this strategy is the fact that no services will - generally - be listening on that IP.  I mean, some _might_, but others may _not_.

Meaning that, if I were to try, say, `telnet debian 25`, (specifically, the local-only `smtp` deamon) it will fail, whereas that would have worked if the name had been mapped either as `127.0.0.1 debian` on its own, or as a `localhost` alias: `127.0.0.1 localhost debian`. So, why not do that instead? Why bother with `127.0.1.1` at all?